# Problem with formula with TIMEVALUE()

Tags: formula, time

I want to have a field that can be used as the basis for 5-minute buckets. So, for example 9:45, 9:46 ... 9:49 should all result in 9:45.

Computations with time values are a bit awkward, at least for me, but this `Time` formula should give the proper time:

```
TIMEVALUE(
TEXT(HOUR(TIMEVALUE(Date_time__c)) + 1) + ':' +
IF(MINUTE(TIMEVALUE(Date_time__c)) < 10, '0', '') +
TEXT(5 * FLOOR(MINUTE(TIMEVALUE(Date_time__c)) / 5)) +
':00.000'
)
```

But this doesn't work, I will explain what happens later on.

A simpler attempt is this `Text` formula:

```
TEXT(HOUR(TIMEVALUE(Date_time__c)) + 1) + ':' +
IF(MINUTE(TIMEVALUE(Date_time__c)) < 10, '0', '') +
TEXT(5 * FLOOR(MINUTE(TIMEVALUE(Date_time__c)) / 5)) +
':00.000'
```

This produces, for example, 9:45:00.000. But using this formula in a formula that uses `TIMEVALUE()` doesn't work: when the `Time` formula is `TIMEVALUE('9:45:00.000')`, I get 9:45 as a result. When I put the `Text` formula, that I quoted above, in a separate field `time_text__c` and try to use `TIMEVALUE(time_text__c)`, I get empty values in list views and an error in a report:

```
An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1528268210-25120 (1696119439)
```

Summarizing, when I copy the values that the text formula produces into `TIMEVALUE()`, it works. But when I try to use the actual formula, which produces that exact text, I get empty results or errors.

Comment: Is there any customization in your org. Because I tried using the below formule `TIMEVALUE(TEXT(HOUR(TIMEVALUE(Date_time__c)) + 1) + ':' +
IF(MINUTE(TIMEVALUE(Date_time__c)) < 10, '0', '') +
TEXT(5 * FLOOR(MINUTE(TIMEVALUE(Date_time__c)) / 5)) +
':00.000')` and given some datatime. It is working as expected. Can you confirm what Datetime value you are using

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala It's an ordinary DateTime field. I am not aware of any custom settings for this type.

Comment: Did you try the above formula field with return type as Time and What value of date time value you are using

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala I have edited the question, to show the Time and Text formulas. The question already mentioned which values I am using.

Comment: Hi Thanks for confirming on it. I have observed it is not working if the time is less than 10 AM and working when time is greater than 10 AM. There should be some issue in the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you SaiPraveenKakkirala, for getting to the bottom of this.

The final `Time` formula is:

```
TIMEVALUE(
IF(HOUR(TIMEVALUE(Date_time__c)) < 9, '0', '') +
TEXT(HOUR(TIMEVALUE(Date_time__c)) + 1) + ':' +
IF(MINUTE(TIMEVALUE(Date_time__c)) < 10, '0', '') +
TEXT(5 * FLOOR(MINUTE(TIMEVALUE(Date_time__c)) / 5)) +
':00.000'
)
```

So an extra 0 had to be inserted for all hours 0 - 9 (the formula looks funny because my company has timezone GMT + 1).

This smells like a Salesforce bug: if I have a `Time` formula `TIMEVALUE('9:45:00.000')`, I get a proper time 9:45. But if I have a `Text` formula that produces a Text `'9:45:00.000'` and I use that in a `Time` formula, then all of a sudden things stop working (list view, report).